# libimobile is not working with iOS 10.0 beta version

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, command, ios10

I am using libimobiledevice in my iOS project. I upgrade my iphone 6sPlus to iOS 10.0 beta version. i fired ideviceinfo command from my mac and get the response : **Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -5**

Any one know about this error??

when i am trying to install my ipa through ideviceinstaller, there I am having the following error: **Could not connect to lockdownd. Exiting.**

please let me know if someone know's the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems with `ideviceinstaller` too, so at least I have started to use `cfgutil`.

It's a CLI tool of Apple Configurator 2, always up-to-date and reliable, works well with iOS beta versions.

Just download the free app from the App Store: [https://itunes.apple.com/hu/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344](https://itunes.apple.com/hu/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12)

Start the app then select "Apple Configurator 2 > Install Automation Tools" from the upper left menu.

To install/uninstall apps:

```
cfgutil --ecid $ECID remove-app $BUNDLE_ID_OF_INSTALLED_APP;
cfgutil --ecid $ECID install-app $PATH_TO_IPA_OR_APP_FOLDER;
```

To get ECID, connect an iOS device and run the following command:

```
cfgutil list
```

**OR**

This has helped my colleague.

Disconnect all iOS devices, then:

```
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller -g
brew uninstall libimobiledevice -g
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice -g
brew install ideviceinstaller -g
```

Connect an iOS device, and choose "Trust" when prompted, after that:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/db/lockdown/*
```

Then add more privileges to iTunes cache folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: updates to macOS, iTunes, and probably other Apple software will (correctly) reset the permissions on /var/db/lockdown.

The best solution here is to get the latest libimobiledevice, which has a fix for this particular issue:

```
brew uninstall libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew link --overwrite libimobiledevice
```